# what are the basic steps to deploy a sharepoint j2010 project to a production server?

Tags: deployment, production

after we finish the development / testing of a sharepoint we need to deploy it on the customer's production server.

I was wondering what are the basic steps to do that.

correct / add to the following please:

1. Backup the web application from the development server.
2. Get all project WSPs.
3. Restore the backup on the production server.
4. Add & Install solutions packages (WSPs) into the web application on the prod. server.

I suppose that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this depends largely on the complexity of your solution.

Testing your WSPs on a blank Pre-production server with a single web application would be a good start.

I'm curious though - why backup/restore the web application?

If you have branding, list definitions, content types to deploy, these can all be created in VS2010 projects then bundled out as WSPs.

If you have a site structure, you can save the site structure as a template (downloads as WSP) then deploy that (should work easily if you don't have much custom code in the sites, otherwise you'll have to ensure any and all necessary features are available on the production server).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Love, you had given me something I really needed , "the possibility to build the whole solution within visual studio. The method we're using in my company is designing the masterpages within the designer. create webparts only in visual studio, create pages in either the browser or SPD. and then we create pages and throw those webparts on them. I believe there's a more professional way, like you said. so we can create everything in visual studio including Masterpages, Site pages, content types? am I missing something?

Comment: you could do, what we've done in the past is have a designer do all the branding (masterpage, css, images) and we structure it into a Feature so it can be deployed and switched on/off. This was in 2007 with WSPBuilder though, but I assume the same is still possible in 2010.